# Download all .m4s files of a mpeg dash stream

Tags: video, streaming, mpd, mpeg-dash

When I open [this page](http://www.ceskatelevize.cz/ivysilani/10600513780-anca-a-pepik/214543116030007-stryc-rene) I can see in Firefox Web Developer Tools / "Network" tab that the page loads files with `.mpd` extension.
And then every few seconds it loads a file/stream with `.m4s` extension named like

```
000000.m4s
000001.m4s
```

How can I download the whole streamed video of this kind?

I think I need to download all .m4s segments but do not know the Linux command or the Windows software to do it. Then I will need to merge these files to a single .mp4

I already tried [InviDownloader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/invidownloader/), but it has numerous problems.

Comment: I tried your sample site with [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) and I was able to download it. The software automatically merges them into one file

Comment: @nixda thx, youtube-dl worked! Thank you. [Here](https://internetlifeforum.com/computers-technology/7701-how-use-youtube-dl-exe-windows/) is how to setup it on the Windows.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can do this using VLC Media Player - menu "Media / Convert-Save / Network" then paste the URL of the mpd file.

Answer (score 23):

Answering the question "How can I download the whole streamed video of this kind?"

You can use youtube-dl on the DASH mpd manifest URL to download the video, it worked for me.

```
youtube-dl {mpd_url}
```

Maybe you should make clear in the title if you really want these intermediate m2s files or you just want the whole video file.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: Nice! Did not know that [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) can deal with DASH streams.

Comment: That's good news, but what do when I get this error: `WARNING: Could not send HEAD request to https://ivys-vst09-6.o2tv.cz/atip/d2560c21d68b9e22bec2bbd624c618cd/1599203098571/61924494877602384-pc.mpd?userId=b090f86c-e193-4ad9-a8ac-ec77d37f334f: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>` It seems that the host `ivys-vst09-6.o2tv.cz` cannot be normally resolved. But I see it perfectly resolved when I inspect the chunked transfers in the Network-Monitor of the browser.

Comment: @Zababa I don't have a getaddrinfo error on my side, just a rather standard "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden". Can you curl this URL in your terminal? If you see the 403 error, I'd say to use some cookie options that you import from your browser to solve this.

Comment: This still works, as of today - I was using youtube-dl version, `2017.11.26`

Answer (score 9):

1) download IS.mp4 and all *.m4s for video (use `wget`) and merge IS.mp4 and *.m4s to one file video.mp4

2) download IS.mp4 and all *.m4s for audio and merge IS.mp4 and *.m4s to one file audio.mp4

3) merge video and audio into one file (use `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -c copy movie.mkv`)

**EDIT**

Example how to download audio stream:

```
echo "IS.mp4" >"links.txt"
seq -f "%06g.m4s" 0 394 >>"links.txt"
wget -i "links.txt" -O "audio.mp4" -B "http://80.188.78.212/aa/ffc8a55fe6f203b0bffecb73efacb69b/1494953435522/eda9c6f7b1e3de68db8e3e5dc0d14fc7/dna-61924494877285694-pc/1002-1502/"
```

Initial part for audio stream is IS.mp4, audio consists of 394 parts (in a format of 6 digits) and base URL path for audio stream is `http://80.188..../1002-1502/`. All these information can be obtained from `.mpd` file.

NOTE: base URL of audio and video stream is changed eachtime you play the video

Comment: >>> download IS.mp4 and all *.m4s for audio and merge IS.mp4 and *.m4s to one file audio.mp4
>>> HOW?

Comment: see example above

Comment: @Unsociableape What if m4s files have a hash instead of a number increasing in ᴜʀʟ ? In that case, it seems a specific tool is required…

Comment: @user2284570 vimeo have segments in json file, there is audio base url, base64 of audio init segment, audio segment list with start time, end time and url. The same also for video.

Comment: @Unsociableape , thank you,  works perfectly !