# Download streaming video with many xhr parts separated for audio and video

Tags: google-chrome, video, streaming, google-chrome-devtools

I want to download a streaming video. When I go to Chrome DevTools -> Network instead of a link to the mp4 video I find many links like `...hd4b.mp4/fragment-1-v1.m4s` and other like `...a1.m4s` for audio. There are also an initial `...hd4b.mp4/init-v1.mp4` and `...init-a1.mp4`. There are too many fragments to copy them manually.

So I need to know how to filter all the .m4s fragment links for the .mp4 file I want. There is an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200450/multiple-urls-copy-in-sources-network-tab) that gives me all the links in Networks and after executing it I can paste the links to a file but it gets links that are not part of the .mp4 I want too. It doesn't really matter but it would be nice to get only the links for the `...hd4b.mp4`.

How do I get the video links in one file and the audio ones in another?

What should I do with the `init` links? Add them to the list?

Now that I think, the way to get the links would be going to the end of the video and getting the last number and generating the links modifying the number from one to last. How would I generate the links? [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22319409/4328677).

And then when I have the links [here's the way](https://superuser.com/a/1204556/428047) to download them but how do I merge the video parts?

And when I have the audio and video how do I combine them in the final mp4?

Comment: Use youtube-dl when possible.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**youtube-dl**

Try using the latest version to download the video. If you can't follow the steps.

**First get the links**

In Chrome go to DevTools -> Networks and find the first and last fragment links.
If the links are sequential generate the links like:

```
seq -f "...hd4b.mp4/fragment-%g-v1.m4s" 10 > video-links.txt
```

Where `%g` will go from 1 to 10. If there is an init link it has to be included at the beginning of the `video-links.txt` file.

If the links are not sequential copy them like this:

1. Switch devtools to detached window (click devtools settings icon, click "dock side" undock icon).  Next time you can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.
2. Invoke devtools-for-devtools by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>
3. Run this code to copy the URLs of all/filtered requests to clipboard: `copy(UI.panels.network._networkLogView._dataGrid._rootNode._flatNodes.map(n => n._request._url).join('\n'))`

You can save the code as a Snippet in Sources panel and run it via right-click or Ctrl-Enter:

```
var URLs = UI.panels.network._networkLogView._dataGrid._rootNode._flatNodes.map(n => n._request._url);
copy(URLs.join('\n'));
URLs; // displays it in the console as an expandable array
```

After executing the script the links are in the clipboard so paste them to a file.

**Download video and audio**

```
wget -i "video-links.txt" -O "video.mp4" -B "...hd4b.mp4/"
```

Use the -B option with the base of the URL.

Download the audio following the same steps as for the video.

**Merge video and audio**

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav \
-c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```